# UIPickerView not scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uipickerview

here is my code, I used Google map and `UIPickerView`:

```
-(void)loadView
{

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86 longitude:151.20 zoom:14];
mapViewCustomer = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapViewCustomer.myLocationEnabled = YES;

//    mapView_ = [[GMSMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
//    [self.view addSubview:mapView_];
self.view = mapViewCustomer;

GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
marker.title = @"My location";
;
marker.map = mapViewCustomer;

[marker setIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"location1.png"]];
}
```

and I have a `UIPickerView` in `viewDidLoad`, I tried put it on `viewWillDisappear` or `viewWillApear` but it doesn't work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
pickerViewCustomer = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 162.0, 320.0, 120.0)];
//[pickerViewCustomer setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 162.0, 320.0, 120.0)];

pickerViewCustomer.hidden = YES;
pickerViewCustomer.delegate = self;
pickerViewCustomer.dataSource = self;
pickerViewCustomer.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

arrayDistanceFilters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"5km",@"10km",@"50km",@"100km",@"100km",@"100km",@"100km",@"100km",@"100km",@"100km", nil];
arrayDistanceValues = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:50], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:100], nil];
[pickerViewCustomer selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
[pickerViewCustomer reloadAllComponents];
[self.view addSubview:pickerViewCustomer];
}
```

delegate and data source

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [arrayDistanceFilters count];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [arrayDistanceFilters objectAtIndex:row];
}
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return 40;
}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
}
```

But scrolling does not work. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Refere below link, It's an example with explanation of PickerView. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPickerView_Example

Comment: It is a good example. But it is not my trouble. Seem, the scrolling doesn't work with google map.

Comment: Maybe another view (`UIControl`) is blocking the interaction?

Answer (score 1):

try an other position on the view...
I had also a picker, which wasnt scrolling,too, then i moved the position(in the storyboard) of the picker and it worked...
to switch off autolayout helped also!
not satisfying, but a solution...

Comment: Sadly, this sort of thing is often the answer. Way too often, the solution is to re-create a new file and/or xib, and paste in the code and/or views and constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this working example for more details

[working tutorial](http://cocoamatic.blogspot.in/2010/08/create-uipickerview-programmatically.html)